# Produce all even primes

Tags: code-golf, primes

A prime number is a positive integer that has exactly two divisors 1 and the number itself. For example number 7 is a prime since it is divisible by 1 and 7. Number 1 is not a prime since it has only one divisor. Write a program or function that produces all even prime numbers.

This is a code golf challenge, shortest answer per language wins.

Comment: Wonderful first challenge! However, I don't really think all that background info is related to the challenge, I'm removing it temprarily.

Comment: also I think the name might be a bit unrelated, maybe it should be named something like `even primes`?

Comment: @petStorm You significally changed the requirements of the challenge. From an output of `[2]`, you changed it into `2`. Given the challenge, that's a significant part. You should never do that.

Comment: Everything about this challenge feels like April Fools happened 9 days too late...

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Producing *all* numbers would evidently require list-wrapping, no? (I was surprised that I haven't specified enough.)

Comment: However, now you can output a newline-separated list instead of a cumbersome JS-specific IO format! :(

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate You have a good point. The previous challenge employs a [Cumbersome I/O format.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/92069) It doesn't allow people to output a list joined with the newline, and it forces answerers to output in their raw form.

Comment: You seem to assume that there are only finitely many even prime numbers. Can you refer to a theorem that supports this assumption? (OTOH, do even prime numbers exist?)

Comment: @petStorm you haven't proved that all other even numbers have factors other than 2, therefore I claim there are infinitely many even primes.

Comment: @ChristianSievers According to the definition, all even numbers are divisible by 2, they can be represented as 2n. According to the definition of primes, since the only integral factors of 1x2 is 1 and 2 (there are no integers between them that can divide them), 1x2 fullfills the definition of primes. This proves that 2 is a prime. However, 2x2, 3x2, and so on don't fullfill the defintion, since given that they are divisible by the prime 2, in order to be a prime, their only other factor has to be 1. However, these numbers divided by 2 do not result in 1, which means that they are not prime.

Answer (score 7):

## [Visual Basic .NET (VBC)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.12.0/#vbnet-compiler), 0 bytes

They added this neat function that an empty program outputs a list of the even primes via the exit code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8ssLk3M0U1KLM5M1s1LLdEtS0r@DwQA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Noxan](https://github.com/TheSecondComing123/Noxan), 1 byte

```
2
```

Implicitly prints out 2.

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 14 bytes

```
-[>+<-----]>-.
```

`-[>+<-----]>` is a script to generate 50 (which is the ascii code of 2) from https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants#50, and then `.` outputs it

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pO20YXBGLtdPX@/wcA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Width](https://github.com/stestoltz/Width), 3 bytes

Curious and hoping to try it. Not short at all, since it's designed for [restricted-source](/questions/tagged/restricted-source).

Unfortunately in Width, numbers don't have the privilege of being implicitly printed. :(

```
Gfm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K89MKcn4/989Lff/fwA)

### Explanation

```
G     Start a string
 fm   Codepoint 18 in the custom code page ('2')
      Implicit end quote
      Implicit print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Nandy](https://github.com/EdgyNerd/Nandy), 12 bytes

<sup><sup>－２　Ｔｈａｎｋｓ　to　[Ｋｅｖｉｎ　Ｃｒｕｉｊｓｓｅｎ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).</sup></sup>

```
::#oo>oo>o>o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vMS6n8/9/KSjk/3w6E7PL//wcA)

## Explanation

```
::#          Generate a 1 bit
   oo        Output 1 twice
     >       Roll the stack
      oo     Output 0 twice
        >o>o Output 1 and 0

This makes the binary codepoint of ASCII 2. 110010
```

Comment: I don't know Nandy at all, but can't you drop the first two `oo` to make the binary `110010`? Seem to work just fine on TIO.

Answer (score 3):

### [+-=](https://esolangs.org/wiki/%2B-), 3 bytes

```
++=
```

Add the accumulator by 3, then output the number.

Answer (score 3):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), 11 bytes

```
v<<>>
>(%2@
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/v8zGxs6Oy05D1cjh/38A) or [verify that it's deterministic](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/v8zGxs6Oy05D1cjh////umEA).

#### Explanation:

**Explanation of the language in general:**

Lost is a 2D path-walking language. Most 2D path-walking languages start at the top-left position and travel towards the right by default. Lost is unique however, in that ***both the start position AND starting direction it travels in is completely random***. So making the program deterministic, meaning it will have the same output regardless of where it starts or travels, can be quite tricky.

A Lost program of 2 rows and 5 characters per row can have 40 possible program flows. It can start on any one of the 10 characters in the program, and it can start traveling up/north, down/south, left/west, or right/east.

In Lost you therefore want to lead everything to a starting position, so it'll follow the designed path you want it to. In addition, you'll usually have to clean the stack when it starts somewhere in the middle.

**Explanation of the program:**

All arrows will lead the path towards the `>` on the second line. From there, the program flow is as follows:

- `>`: Travel in a east/right direction.
- `(`: Pop the top of the stack (and push it to the scope). This is to clean a potential 2 that was already pushed.
- `%`: Put the safety 'off'. In a Lost program, an `@` will terminate the program, but only when the safety is 'off'. When the program starts, the safety is always 'on' by default, otherwise a program flow starting at the exit character `@` would immediately terminate without doing anything. The `%` will turn this safety 'off', so when we now encounter an `@` the program will terminate (if the safety is still 'on', the `@` will be a no-op instead).
- `2`: Push a 2
- `@`: Terminate the program if the safety is 'off' (which it is at this point). After which all the values on the stack will be output implicitly with space separator, which in this case is just the `2`.

Note that the top line could have been `v<<<<`, but that the reversed part `>>` will wrap-around to the other side, making the path shorter and therefore the performance slightly better. The byte-count remains the same anyway, so why not.

Answer (score 3):

## [Malbolge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/malbolge), 8 bytes

```
D'<;:^"J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MScrPSU/9/99F3cbaKk7J6/9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 4 bytes

```java
v->2
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY2xDoMwEEN3vuLGZCBDV1T@oCxIXaoO15BWoeFA5BKpqvj2NKEslvws2yNGrMfhnbRD7@GClr4VgCU26xO1ga7YHYAW19kOEGWT0VZl8YxsNXRAcE6xbk@pKXgJD5fxkcZSmvKw6Hm19LrdAeV/tf94NpOaA6slRyxIaUHBOXl8bOkH)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->  // Method with empty unused parameter and integer return-type
  2  //  Return 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 10 bytes

```
[S S S T    S N
_Push_2][T  N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgVOBi5NLgfP/fwA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer n = 2
Print n as integer to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 7 bytes

```python
exit(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7Uis0TDSPP/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>15</s> <s>14</s></sup> 12 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [petStorm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92069/petstorm)!!!
Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!

```c
a;f(){a|=2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/ROk1DszqxxtbIuvZ/bmJmHpBXUJSZV5KmoaSaoqQDlNUEygAA)

Comment: `a;f(){a|=2;}` for 12 bytes

Comment: @Arnauld Very nice - thanks! :-)

Comment: @l4m2 It's a hack is to load register `EAX` with the function's return value.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) without literals, 15 bytes

```python
exit(-~-~int())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7Uis0RDt063LjOvRENT8/9/AA)

Comment: `int()` produces 0? Cool.

Comment: I originally put "Python 3 without literals" but that was a bit specific. I put literals again.

Comment: What exactly does "without literals" mean? Do strings count too?

Comment: Yes, and booleans, and lists, and dictionaries, basically everything other than builtin functions, maybe modules, and variables.

Answer (score 1):

## [TrumpScript](https://github.com/samshadwell/TrumpScript), 3 bytes

```
a
b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KykqzS0oTi7KLCj5/z@RK@n/fwA)

The error message in the output contains all even prime numbers and no other numbers. Well no-one said the output couldn't include other non-numeric text.

The exception message is a bit special:

**Exception: Trump will ensure that 'America is great'**

As a (not very much) more serious effort (without errors):

## [TrumpScript](https://github.com/samshadwell/TrumpScript), 36 bytes

```
say 1000002-1000000
America is great
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KykqzS0oTi7KLCj5/784sVLB0AAEjHQhtAGXY25qUWZyokJmsUJ6UWoiUBUA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Enlist](https://github.com/alexander-liao/enlist), 1 byte

```
2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83LySwu@f/f6P9/AA)

Just picked a random language on TIO and it worked. Oh well, it's another language to add to the list.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 2 bytes

```
2h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/3wiIAQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
2
```

it pushes 2 into the stack and then implicitly outputs it, pretty boring

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f6P9/AA)

Comment: Ahh, a polyglot with almost every golfing language :)

Comment: not really, as ¸ encloses the number in an array and I think it's unique to 05AB1E, but can probably be converted to almost any other golfing language

Comment: oh the post have been edited so now I don't need to output JSON, so it's 1 byte

Comment: [`Y`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/8v9/AA) is an alternative 1-byte solution for 05AB1E ;)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 7 bytes

```python
print 2
```

### Explaination

prints 2

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EAcgAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 6 bytes

```bash
echo 2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/B6P9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 4 bytes

```javascript
v=>2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/M1s7of3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 12 bytes

```
END{print 2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/f1c@luqAoM69Ewaj2/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Lenguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage), 979,674,373,772 bytes

## [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary), 2,063,923,527,196 bytes

Programs consists of 2063923527196 and 979674373772 amount of characters of your own choosing.

Port of [*CommandMaster*'s brainfuck answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203237/52210).

[Try it online in brainfuck.](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pO20YXBGLtdPX@/wcA)

Byte-counts generated by [this program](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fKTQvsajSSkHJXsnORltXTyc6VskzOPvQmvhMJb/8EoXEnJz88tQUhZJ8heKSxKIShfLMkgyFRAU7pcOrLc5tqtXhUvJJzUsvTUxPBRuirWtnQ7Qh2jBD/v/XjbbTttEFgVg7XT0A) I wrote in [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands).

Answer (score 0):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 4 bytes

```
2a1o
```

Simply adds 2 to the register and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

## [J](https://jsoftware.com), 1 byte

```
2
```

### Explanation

```
2 NB. 2
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uselesslang](https://github.com/Fmbalbuena/Uselesslang), 4 bytes

```
>>.
```

(There is trailing space)

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 3 bytes

```
2n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yjP@v9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [CellTail](https://github.com/mousetail/CellTail), 8 bytes

```
I=2;O=N;
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/CellTail/#ST0yO089Tjs=)

Explanation:

- `I=2` sets the initial state to 2.
- `O=N` sets the output format to numbers.

I should really get around to setting up these things as flags.